# VB.NET email validation with Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation

I've tried implementing a rather simple email validation function that seems return a false match even though the input is a valid email. I have searched for any issues with the existing regex but it seems to be correct.

Even though the match returns a false value the program is stepping to the next validation level (which it shouldn't).

Here is the email validation function.

```
Function EmailAddressChecker(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean
        Dim regExPattern As String = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"
        Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailAddress, regExPattern)
        If emailAddressMatch.Success Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
End Function
```

And for the form validation that calls upon the email validation function.

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailTextBox.Text) OrElse EmailAddressChecker(EmailTextBox.ToString)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email addresss")
            Return False
End If
```

The call for all of this happens on an click event which triggers a cascading serious of If statements checking to see if all the fields are set.

Skipping a large chunk of code the click event asks if "AreFieldsSet <> True". Inside of the "AreFieldsSet" function contains all the validation for multiple inputs; one of which is the email validation if statement.

Comment: We need to see the context this is called in - that's likely where the issue is.

Comment: You may also want to consider instantiating a System.Net.Mail.MailAddress object in a try catch for e-mail address validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the emails in UpperCase? If they aren't, they won't match.

If you want to modify the Regex so that it is Case insensitive, use this:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate the email address you need to use the IsMatch function of the Regex  object, it evaluate if the entry email address is valid.

```
Function EmailAddressChecker(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean
   Dim r As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = Nothing
    Dim regExPattern As String = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"

    If r.IsMatch(emailAddress ,regExPattern ) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but isn't this functionally equivalent to what the original code does? Less code, but both should do the same thing.

Comment: I did notice however that the email address is equal to ""System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: abc@aosdf". This obviously needs to be dealt with. I think I had a problem with this before.. Fix is something like "public override string ToString()" ????

Comment: Accessing the textbox via `txtMyTextbox.Text` should return the email string in its purest form. Calling `txtMyTextBox.ToString()` should return the string you provided "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: abc@aosdf".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for your form validation `If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailTextBox.Text) OrElse EmailAddressChecker(EmailTextBox.ToString)<>true) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email addresss")
            Return False
End If`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function ValidEmailAddress(ByVal emailAddress As String, ByRef errorMessage As String) As Boolean    

       If emailAddress.IndexOf("@") > -1 Then
        If (emailAddress.IndexOf(".", emailAddress.IndexOf("@")) > emailAddress.IndexOf("@")) AndAlso emailAddress.Split(".").Length > 0 AndAlso emailAddress.Split(".")(1) <> "" Then
            errorMessage = ""
            Return True
        End If
    End If      
    Return False
End Function
```